# Recommended Linux kernel settings for Node.js

Tags: linux, node.js

Our node.js app is going to be heavily loaded and so I wonder if there are Linux (Ubuntu server) kernel settings that I should configure appropriately?

For now I was thinking about limit of open file descriptors:

```
cat /etc/security/limits.d/nodeuser.conf
nodeuser     soft    nofile  65535
nodeuser     hard    nofile  65535
```

Are there any other kernel/user process tunables that should have some recommended values for Node.js?

Comment: I suppose not. In my experience node.js works out of the box on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this great post in the past:

https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-nginx-node-js-and-networking-for-heavy-workloads

In my experience, the most important thing is to reduce time connections spend in TIME_WAIT after being closed (`net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` and `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`). Otherwise, you can run out of open ports quick.

As you suggested, you also need to increase the number of file descriptors.